# AWS Java SDK 2.0 get s3 object meta only

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to get S3 Object metadata without downloading the whole file?
Looks like v 1.0 has this feature, but I can't find it for 2.0.

Comment: What would you like to get?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I put some meta to `Map<String, String>` for every object. So sometimes I heed to collect all metas or check if meta exists or something else.

Comment: @AmitBaranes this meta: `PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).metadata(Map("1" -> "2").asJava).build()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s3Client.headObject(...).metadata()